# Display days ago instead of date

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I have a comment area on my website and each comment displays when it was posted in the normal date format (05/Nov/2012)... But I would like to display '1 day ago' of even '3 hours ago' instead of the normal format... Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT p.poll_id, p.title, date_format(c.posted, '%D %b %y') as time, COUNT( c.poll_id ) AS count, u.username
FROM users AS u
JOIN polls AS p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON p.poll_id = c.poll_id
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: *05/Nov/2012* is not "normal"

Comment: You're overthinking the HTML tags; just indent your code using the `{}` button above the text window, and focus more on getting your capitalization correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [date difference function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)  to evaluate date difference

```
SELECT p.poll_id, p.title,  DATEDIFF(NOW(), c.posted) AS daysold, COUNT( c.poll_id ) AS   count, u.username
  FROM users AS u
  JOIN polls AS p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
  LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON p.poll_id = c.poll_id
  LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Why not leave this just as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: cause it seems like a legit answer?! ;)